# Write text input using the touchscreen?

Tags: touchscreen

How can I write text inputs using the touchscreen display?

The touchscreen is working well, but for example, if I want to write in the terminal something, instead of writing it selects the terminal lines.

So, how could I write `ls` using the touchscreen pencil and then run the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need software that reads handwriting.

A quick look around found [this](https://github.com/haywood/Handwriting-Recognition-System) github project.

Alternatively you could opt for an onscreen keyboard if you are running a GUI.

```
sudo apt-get install matchbox-keyboard
```

Comment: And is it possible to start it before running the GUI, just in the terminal where you write `startx`? :)

Comment: I don't think that's possible... :)

Comment: No that won't work.
If it doesn't need to be attached to the Pi you could go with something like
[Juice SSH](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh&hl=en)